# When i using if statement there is something i cant explain when i write this code

Tags: c

When i using if statement i there something i cant explain when i write this code

```
if(score1 > score2)
{ printf("player 1 wins! \n");
}

if(score2 > score1)
{ printf("player 2 wins! \n");
} else
{ printf("tie \n");
}
```

the else statement evaluated althought the first condition is correct ===> how else statement evaluated and the first condition evaluated too i cant explain this this is the

output(player 1 wins!

tie )

Comment: You need to use `if ... else if ... else`. If you start using proper code formatting, you will see which else that belongs to which `if`.

Comment: Getting into the habit of doing strict consistent indentation often helps with analysis of logic-based control structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `if`, you can write an `if` right after and it will be the same as `else if`, but only in the case you returned when the first `if` condition matched:

For example:

```
if (some_condition) {
  // do something
  return; // you could return anything, what matters is that the function exits
}

// same as else if here because when the first if matches, it exits the function
if (some_other_condition) {
   // do something else
   // you could also return something in here if you wanted an equivalent of if else after this
}
```

In your case, you are not returning, so the two first ifs are not mutually exclusive, you can either rewrite explicitly if/else, or return inside an if block.

Comment: thank you so much this the best explanation i got it and you add me the  part of return statement thank you again

Answer (score 0):

In your code the `else` statement evaluates based on the result of the second `if` statement. If you want it to evaluate based on both `if`s, you need to use `else if` like that:

```
if (condition) {
  // your code here
} else if (condition) {
  // your code here
} else {
  // your code here
}
```

Specifically for you example:

```
if (score1 > score2) {
  printf("player 1 wins! \n");
} else if (score2 > score1) {
  printf("player 2 wins! \n");
} else {
  printf("tie \n");
}
```